# Target function within var ==> TypeError: Grid.prevItemsEvents is not a function

Tags: jquery

I need to make a previous and next button for an image grid

```
$prev=$( '<input id="prev" type="button" value="prev" onclick="prev();" />' );
```

I tried  to call a function within a var

```
var Grid = (function() {
...
function prevItemsEvents( $items ) {
...
```

But i can't seem to get this to work

```
function prev() {$(function(){Grid.prevItemsEvents();})};
```

I get this error

TypeError: Grid.prevItemsEvents is not a function

Thx for the input

the entire code

```
/*
* debouncedresize: special jQuery event that happens once after a window resize
*
* latest version and complete README available on Github:
* https://github.com/louisremi/jquery-smartresize/blob/master/jquery.debouncedresize.js
*
* Copyright 2011 @louis_remi
* Licensed under the MIT license.
*/
var $event = $.event,
$special,
resizeTimeout;

$special = $event.special.debouncedresize = {
    setup: function() {
        $( this ).on( "resize", $special.handler );
    },
    teardown: function() {
        $( this ).off( "resize", $special.handler );
    },
    handler: function( event, execAsap ) {
        // Save the context
        var context = this,
            args = arguments,
            dispatch = function() {
                // set correct event type
                event.type = "debouncedresize";
                $event.dispatch.apply( context, args );
            };

        if ( resizeTimeout ) {
            clearTimeout( resizeTimeout );
        }

        execAsap ?
            dispatch() :
            resizeTimeout = setTimeout( dispatch, $special.threshold );
    },
    threshold: 250
};

// ======================= imagesLoaded Plugin ===============================
// https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded

// $('#my-container').imagesLoaded(myFunction)
// execute a callback when all images have loaded.
// needed because .load() doesn't work on cached images

// callback function gets image collection as argument
//  this is the container

// original: MIT license. Paul Irish. 2010.
// contributors: Oren Solomianik, David DeSandro, Yiannis Chatzikonstantinou

// blank image data-uri bypasses webkit log warning (thx doug jones)
var BLANK = 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///ywAAAAAAQABAAACAUwAOw==';

$.fn.imagesLoaded = function( callback ) {
    var $this = this,
        deferred = $.isFunction($.Deferred) ? $.Deferred() : 0,
        hasNotify = $.isFunction(deferred.notify),
        $images = $this.find('img').add( $this.filter('img') ),
        loaded = [],
        proper = [],
        broken = [];

    // Register deferred callbacks
    if ($.isPlainObject(callback)) {
        $.each(callback, function (key, value) {
            if (key === 'callback') {
                callback = value;
            } else if (deferred) {
                deferred[key](value);
            }
        });
    }

    function doneLoading() {
        var $proper = $(proper),
            $broken = $(broken);

        if ( deferred ) {
            if ( broken.length ) {
                deferred.reject( $images, $proper, $broken );
            } else {
                deferred.resolve( $images );
            }
        }

        if ( $.isFunction( callback ) ) {
            callback.call( $this, $images, $proper, $broken );
        }
    }

    function imgLoaded( img, isBroken ) {
        // don't proceed if BLANK image, or image is already loaded
        if ( img.src === BLANK || $.inArray( img, loaded ) !== -1 ) {
            return;
        }

        // store element in loaded images array
        loaded.push( img );

        // keep track of broken and properly loaded images
        if ( isBroken ) {
            broken.push( img );
        } else {
            proper.push( img );
        }

        // cache image and its state for future calls
        $.data( img, 'imagesLoaded', { isBroken: isBroken, src: img.src } );

        // trigger deferred progress method if present
        if ( hasNotify ) {
            deferred.notifyWith( $(img), [ isBroken, $images, $(proper), $(broken) ] );
        }

        // call doneLoading and clean listeners if all images are loaded
        if ( $images.length === loaded.length ){
            setTimeout( doneLoading );
            $images.unbind( '.imagesLoaded' );
        }
    }

    // if no images, trigger immediately
    if ( !$images.length ) {
        doneLoading();
    } else {
        $images.bind( 'load.imagesLoaded error.imagesLoaded', function( event ){
            // trigger imgLoaded
            imgLoaded( event.target, event.type === 'error' );
        }).each( function( i, el ) {
            var src = el.src;

            // find out if this image has been already checked for status
            // if it was, and src has not changed, call imgLoaded on it
            var cached = $.data( el, 'imagesLoaded' );
            if ( cached && cached.src === src ) {
                imgLoaded( el, cached.isBroken );
                return;
            }

            // if complete is true and browser supports natural sizes, try
            // to check for image status manually
            if ( el.complete && el.naturalWidth !== undefined ) {
                imgLoaded( el, el.naturalWidth === 0 || el.naturalHeight === 0 );
                return;
            }

            // cached images don't fire load sometimes, so we reset src, but only when
            // dealing with IE, or image is complete (loaded) and failed manual check
            // webkit hack from http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-dev/browse_thread/thread/eee6ab7b2da50e1f
            if ( el.readyState || el.complete ) {
                el.src = BLANK;
                el.src = src;
            }
        });
    }

    return deferred ? deferred.promise( $this ) : $this;
};

var Grid = (function() {

        // list of items
    var $grid = $( '#og-grid' ),
        // the items
        $items = $grid.children( 'li' ),
        // current expanded item's index
        current = -1,
        // position (top) of the expanded item
        // used to know if the preview will expand in a different row
        previewPos = -1,
        // extra amount of pixels to scroll the window
        scrollExtra = 0,
        // extra margin when expanded (between preview overlay and the next items)
        marginExpanded = 10,
        $window = $( window ), winsize,
        $body = $( 'html, body' ),
        // transitionend events
        transEndEventNames = {
            'WebkitTransition' : 'webkitTransitionEnd',
            'MozTransition' : 'transitionend',
            'OTransition' : 'oTransitionEnd',
            'msTransition' : 'MSTransitionEnd',
            'transition' : 'transitionend'
        },
        transEndEventName = transEndEventNames[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'transition' ) ],
        // support for csstransitions
        support = Modernizr.csstransitions,
        // default settings
        settings = {
            minHeight : 500,
            speed : 350,
            easing : 'ease'
        };

    function init( config ) {

        // the settings..
        settings = $.extend( true, {}, settings, config );

        // preload all images
        $grid.imagesLoaded( function() {

            // save item´s size and offset
            saveItemInfo( true );
            // get window´s size
            getWinSize();
            // initialize some events
            initEvents();

        } );

    }

    // add more items to the grid.
    // the new items need to appended to the grid.
    // after that call Grid.addItems(theItems);
    function addItems( $newitems ) {

        $items = $items.add( $newitems );

        $newitems.each( function() {
            var $item = $( this );
            $item.data( {
                offsetTop : $item.offset().top,
                height : $item.height()
            } );
        } );

        initItemsEvents( $newitems );

    }

    // saves the item´s offset top and height (if saveheight is true)
    function saveItemInfo( saveheight ) {
        $items.each( function() {
            var $item = $( this );
            $item.data( 'offsetTop', $item.offset().top );
            if( saveheight ) {
                $item.data( 'height', $item.height() );
            }
        } );
    }

    function initEvents() {

        // when clicking an item, show the preview with the item´s info and large image.
        // close the item if already expanded.
        // also close if clicking on the item´s cross
        initItemsEvents( $items );

        // on window resize get the window´s size again
        // reset some values..
        $window.on( 'debouncedresize', function() {

            scrollExtra = 0;
            previewPos = -1;
            // save item´s offset
            saveItemInfo();
            getWinSize();
            var preview = $.data( this, 'preview' );
            if( typeof preview != 'undefined' ) {
                hidePreview();
            }

        } );

    }

    function initItemsEvents( $items ) {
        $items.on( 'click', 'span.og-close', function() {
            hidePreview();
            return false;
        } ).children( 'a' ).on( 'click', function(e) {

            var $item = $( this ).parent();
            // check if item already opened
            current === $item.index() ? hidePreview() : showPreview( $item );
            return false;

        } );
    }

    function nextItemsEvents( $items ) {
        $items.on( 'click', 'span.og-close', function() {
            hidePreview();
            return false;
        } ).children( 'a' ).on( 'click', function(e) {

            var $item = $( this ).parent().next();
            showPreview( $item );
            return false;

        } );
    }


    function prevItemsEvents( $items ) {
        $items.on( 'click', 'span.og-close', function() {
            hidePreview();
            return false;
        } ).children( 'a' ).on( 'click', function(e) {

            var $item = $( this ).parent().prev();
            showPreview( $item );
            return false;

        } );
    }

    function getWinSize() {
        winsize = { width : $window.width(), height : $window.height() };
    }

    function showPreview( $item ) {


        var preview = $.data( this, 'preview' ),
            // item´s offset top
            position = $item.data( 'offsetTop' );

        scrollExtra = 0;

        // if a preview exists and previewPos is different (different row) from item´s top then close it
        if( typeof preview != 'undefined' ) {

            // not in the same row
            if( previewPos !== position ) {
                // if position > previewPos then we need to take te current preview´s height in consideration when scrolling the window
                if( position > previewPos ) {
                    scrollExtra = preview.height;
                }
                hidePreview();
            }
            // same row
            else {
                preview.update( $item );
                return false;
            }

        }

        // update previewPos
        previewPos = position;
        // initialize new preview for the clicked item
        preview = $.data( this, 'preview', new Preview( $item ) );
        // expand preview overlay
        preview.open();

    }

    function hidePreview() {
        current = -1;
        var preview = $.data( this, 'preview' );
        preview.close();
        $.removeData( this, 'preview' );
    }

    // the preview obj / overlay
    function Preview( $item ) {
        this.$item = $item;
        this.expandedIdx = this.$item.index();
        this.create();
        this.update();
    }


    Preview.prototype = {
        create : function() {
            // create Preview structure:
            this.$title = $( '<h3></h3>' );
            this.$description = $( '<p></p>' );
            this.$href = $( '<a href="#">Visit website</a>' );
            $next=$( '<input id="next" type="button" value="next" onclick="next();" />' );
            $prev=$( '<input id="prev" type="button" value="prev" onclick="prev();" />' );
            this.$details = $( '<div class="og-details"></div>' ).append( this.$title, this.$description, $prev, $next);
            this.$loading = $( '<div class="og-loading"></div>' );
            this.$fullimage = $( '<div class="og-fullimg"></div>' ).append( this.$loading );
            this.$closePreview = $( '<span class="og-close"></span>' );
            this.$previewInner = $( '<div class="og-expander-inner"></div>' ).append( this.$closePreview, this.$fullimage, this.$details );
            this.$previewEl = $( '<div class="og-expander"></div>' ).append( this.$previewInner );
            // append preview element to the item
            this.$item.append( this.getEl() );
            // set the transitions for the preview and the item
            if( support ) {
                this.setTransition();
            }
        },
        update : function( $item ) {

            if( $item ) {
                this.$item = $item;
            }

            // if already expanded remove class "og-expanded" from current item and add it to new item
            if( current !== -1 ) {
                var $currentItem = $items.eq( current );
                $currentItem.removeClass( 'og-expanded' );
                this.$item.addClass( 'og-expanded' );
                // position the preview correctly
                this.positionPreview();
            }

            // update current value
            current = this.$item.index();

            // update preview´s content
            var $itemEl = this.$item.children( 'a' ),
                eldata = {
                    href : $itemEl.attr( 'href' ),
                    largesrc : $itemEl.data( 'largesrc' ),
                    title : $itemEl.data( 'title' ),
                    description : $itemEl.data( 'description' )
                };

            this.$title.html( eldata.title );
            this.$description.html( eldata.description );
            this.$href.attr( 'href', eldata.href );

            var self = this;

            // remove the current image in the preview
            if( typeof self.$largeImg != 'undefined' ) {
                self.$largeImg.remove();
            }

            // preload large image and add it to the preview
            // for smaller screens we don´t display the large image (the media query will hide the fullimage wrapper)
            if( self.$fullimage.is( ':visible' ) ) {
                this.$loading.show();
                $( '<img/>' ).load( function() {
                    var $img = $( this );
                    if( $img.attr( 'src' ) === self.$item.children('a').data( 'largesrc' ) ) {
                        self.$loading.hide();
                        self.$fullimage.find( 'img' ).remove();
                        self.$largeImg = $img.fadeIn( 350 );
                        self.$fullimage.append( self.$largeImg );
                    }
                } ).attr( 'src', eldata.largesrc ); 
            }

        },
        open : function() {

            setTimeout( $.proxy( function() {   
                // set the height for the preview and the item
                this.setHeights();
                // scroll to position the preview in the right place --- pieterm removed autoscroll
                //this.positionPreview();
            }, this ), 25 );

        },
        close : function() {

            var self = this,
                onEndFn = function() {
                    if( support ) {
                        $( this ).off( transEndEventName );
                    }
                    self.$item.removeClass( 'og-expanded' );
                    self.$previewEl.remove();
                };

            setTimeout( $.proxy( function() {

                if( typeof this.$largeImg !== 'undefined' ) {
                    this.$largeImg.fadeOut( 'fast' );
                }
                this.$previewEl.css( 'height', 0 );
                // the current expanded item (might be different from this.$item)
                var $expandedItem = $items.eq( this.expandedIdx );
                $expandedItem.css( 'height', $expandedItem.data( 'height' ) ).on( transEndEventName, onEndFn );

                if( !support ) {
                    onEndFn.call();
                }

            }, this ), 25 );

            return false;

        },
        calcHeight : function() {

            var heightPreview = winsize.height - this.$item.data( 'height' ) - marginExpanded,
                itemHeight = winsize.height;

            if( heightPreview < settings.minHeight ) {
                heightPreview = settings.minHeight;
                itemHeight = settings.minHeight + this.$item.data( 'height' ) + marginExpanded;
            }

            this.height = heightPreview;
            this.itemHeight = itemHeight;

        },
        setHeights : function() {

            var self = this,
                onEndFn = function() {
                    if( support ) {
                        self.$item.off( transEndEventName );
                    }
                    self.$item.addClass( 'og-expanded' );
                };

            this.calcHeight();
            this.$previewEl.css( 'height', this.height );
            this.$item.css( 'height', this.itemHeight ).on( transEndEventName, onEndFn );

            if( !support ) {
                onEndFn.call();
            }

        },
        positionPreview : function() {

            // scroll page
            // case 1 : preview height + item height fits in window´s height
            // case 2 : preview height + item height does not fit in window´s height and preview height is smaller than window´s height
            // case 3 : preview height + item height does not fit in window´s height and preview height is bigger than window´s height
            var position = this.$item.data( 'offsetTop' ),
                previewOffsetT = this.$previewEl.offset().top - scrollExtra,
                scrollVal = this.height + this.$item.data( 'height' ) + marginExpanded <= winsize.height ? position : this.height < winsize.height ? previewOffsetT - ( winsize.height - this.height ) : previewOffsetT;

            $body.animate( { scrollTop : scrollVal }, settings.speed );

        },
        setTransition  : function() {
            this.$previewEl.css( 'transition', 'height ' + settings.speed + 'ms ' + settings.easing );
            this.$item.css( 'transition', 'height ' + settings.speed + 'ms ' + settings.easing );
        },
        getEl : function() {
            return this.$previewEl;
        }
    }

    return { 
        init : init,
        addItems : addItems
    };

})();

function prev() {$(function(){Grid.prevItemsEvents();})};
function next() {$(function(){Grid.nextItemsEvents();})};
```

html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/grid.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.lazy.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>$(function() {Grid.init();});</script>
<script type="text/javascript">jQuery(document).ready(function() { jQuery(".lazy").lazy(); });</script>
```

Comment: Is the assignment to `Grid` inside another function? If so, it's local to that function, and won't be available to a global function like `prev`.

Comment: It's not relevant to the question, but why are you calling it inside `$(...)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Grid` object is

```
return { 
    init : init,
    addItems : addItems
};
```

so you can call from `Grid` only it. If you want call somthing like `Grid.prevItemsEvents()` you must add in this object this function like

```
return { 
    init : init,
    addItems : addItems,
    prevItemsEvents : prevItemsEvents
};
```

all function declared inside function is private so if you need add something else you just need to add reference to it in returned object

Answer (score 1):

you should do something like this

```
var Grid = (function () {

    return {
        prevItemsEvents: function ($items) {
            //code goes here

        }
    }
})();
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/donce17/nZuG9/)